Создание связанной модели в ASP .NET
не могу понять как правильно создавать связанные объекты. У меня есть цех и оборудование в цехе, при создании оборудования планировалось явное указание в каком оно будет цехе, как это можно реализовать?
Сущность оборудование
public class Machine : IEntity 
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Наименование")]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    [ForeignKey("WorkshopID")]
    public virtual Workshop? Workshop { get; set; }
}

Сущность цех
[Table("Workshops")]
public class Workshop : IEntity
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Наименование")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Machine>? Machines { get; set; }
}


Паттерн репозитория
public virtual async Task Create(T entity)
{
    if (entity != null)
    {
        await _instance.AddAsync(entity);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException();
    }
}

Метод создания в контроллере оборудования
private readonly IRepository<Machine> _machineRepository;
private readonly IRepository<Workshop> _workshopRepository;

public MachinesController(
    IRepository<Machine> machineRepository,
    IRepository<Workshop> workshopRepository)
{
    _machineRepository = machineRepository;
    _workshopRepository = workshopRepository;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var workshops = _workshopRepository.GetList();
    ViewBag.listWorkshops = new SelectList(workshops, "Name");
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,NumberModel,ReleaseDate,Description,ImagePath")] Machine machine)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _machineRepository.Create(machine);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(machine);
}

View страница create с выводом поля select в котором планируется выбрать уже созданный цех
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-select" asp-for="Workshop" asp-items="ViewBag.listWorkshops">
        <option selected>Выберете цех</option>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Workshops)
        {
            <option selected>@ViewBag.Workshops</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

При попытке выгрузить список в select возникает ошибка приведения типа, но мне кажется, что подход в целом неверен.
